# Why is my Unity CharController Dash function not propelling me in the correct direction, despite seemingly correct values..?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been adding some extra movement techniques to a Character Controller in Unity3D. Currently, I'm working on a dash function, but currently, it's behaving very weirdly.

[Dashing Backwards, Works as I want it to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAmhi.png)

[Dashing Forwards, Doesn't work as I want it to...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9eXy.png)

As you can see in the first Image, the silhouttes being essentially where I've dashed, I'm moving in a straight line backwards, as represented by the Green Arrows. However in the second Image, the silhouttes go diagonally to the top left, instead of straight ahead. As represented by the yellow arrows, this time green showing where I want and expect it to go.

```
private void DashFuncW()
{
    if (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - timeOfFirstButton < DoublePressSpan && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && firstButtonPressed)
    {
        Dash(transform.forward);

        firstButtonPressed = false;
        timeOfFirstButton = 0f;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
   {
        timeOfFirstButton = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        firstButtonPressed = true;
   } 
}
private void DashFuncS()
{
    if (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - timeOfFirstButton < DoublePressSpan && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) && firstButtonPressed)
    {
        Dash(-transform.forward);

        firstButtonPressed = false;
        timeOfFirstButton = 0f;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        timeOfFirstButton = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        firstButtonPressed = true;
    }
}
```

These 2 Functions get the double-tap style input and call the actual Dash function while passing it the Direction it needs to go to. As you can see, both use 'transform.forward', just the S key function uses '-transform.forward'. This is what confuses me the most. If it can go one way fine, why can't it go the other way, especially when they're the exact mirror values of one another.

```
    private void Dash(Vector3 Direction)
{
    GameObject WarpClone = Instantiate(gameObject);
    WarpClone.transform.position = transform.position;
    Destroy(WarpClone.GetComponent<CharacterMovement>());
    Destroy(WarpClone.GetComponent<CharacterController>());
    Destroy(WarpClone.GetComponent<Animator>());
    foreach (Transform child in WarpClone.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())
    {
        Destroy(child.GetComponent<Collider>());
        SkinnedMeshRenderer[] SMRs = WarpClone.GetComponentsInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
        MeshRenderer[] MRs = WarpClone.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer>();
        foreach (SkinnedMeshRenderer SMR in SMRs)
        {
            SMR.material = warpMaterial;
        }
        foreach (MeshRenderer MR in MRs)
        {
            MR.material = warpMaterial;
        }
    }
    Destroy(WarpClone, 100f); //100 Seconds for testing
    CC.Move(Direction * dashStrength);
}
```

And this function is the one that creates the silhouettes and actually moves the player. If it matters any, 'dashStrength' is equal to 3, and all 3 of these functions are in a bigger 'Movement' function which moves the character based on Axis input, which runs in the Update() call, as FixedUpdate makes for jittery movement. I cannot for the life of me find out why it won't work properly. I'd appreciate any help :/

Comment: The yellow looks forward to me. The green might be forward from the camera but not the player

Comment: @BugFinder It definitely isn't transform.forward, though. In game, the transform moves move forward on the Z axis but also a bit on the X axis, so it's definitely not just forward. Green should be from the player as it uses transform.forward. Which I tried to show in the backwards one

Comment: But the player is looking off to the left, so forward would be off to the left...

Comment: @BugFinder In those pictures, the player is always looking forwards towards the Z axis, but I think the perspective of the picture skews that a bit. Even if they were facing to the left, If they went straight forwards to the left I'd be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anyone ends up with the same problem somehow, I ended up fixing it by disabling the character controller and changing transform.position like so:

```
    CC.enabled = false;
    transform.position = transform.position + (Direction * dashStrength);
    CC.enabled = true;
```